# How to make a paragraph appear in a certain area in the page using Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, layout

I'm currently creating my own Wordpress page with a customized css layout. How do I make the "content" that is generated via the "Add Pages" appear in a certain part of my layout or div? Which codes do I use in PHP to make the paragraph (or html codes) I type in the "Add pages" appear in that particular div?

The image below would help support my explanation:

[image: generate-paragraph inside a certain div]

I hope someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing the page in PHP on the backend, use this code to get a post.  If you are using the page editor, there's a way to enable PHP in your post (it will compromise security though):

```
$my_postid = 12;//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
```

Comment: Hi Luke. Will I just have to apply these php codes in between a <div class="example"></div> where I want the paragraph or html code to appear? Thank you.

Comment: That's correct, are you inserting it through the backend (PHP file) or are you calling it from a page (from the database)>

Comment: Hi. I've tried doing your code above but what you gave is target specific in terms of the id.. I've inserted the code inside the "page.php" file. About your question above- I guess I'm trying to insert it in a php file (page.php).

Comment: Take a look here Niccolo, I think this might be what you're looking for.  This is a standard page template:

http://www.heidicool.com/samplewordpress/theme-files/page-php/

Comment: Hi Luke! I was put in the right direction with the link you gave. I used "<?php the_content(); ?>" to make the paragraph appear. Thanks a lot!